# python: def function with error exceptions does not work correctly

Tags: python

i defined a function and it's not working correctly:

```
def ppb2mugpm3(ppb):
    try:
        type(ppb) in [int,float]
    except TypeError as TE:
        "Type is not int or float"
    try:
        ppb>0
    except ValueError as VE:
        "Value is <0"
    return float(ppb*2.15)
```

it should raise a TypeError exception when type is not int or float and a ValueError exception if value<0.
if I use eg "n" as ppb, python tells me:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1018/474705291.py in ppb2mugpm3(ppb)
     13     try:
---> 14         ppb>0
     15     except ValueError as ValueError:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1018/474705291.py in <module>
     62     return str(d)+"."+m+"."+str(j)
     63 
---> 64 ppb2mugpm3("n")

/tmp/ipykernel_1018/474705291.py in ppb2mugpm3(ppb)
     13     try:
     14         ppb>0
---> 15     except ValueError as ValueError:
     16         "Value is <0"
     17     return float(ppb*2.15)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ValueError' referenced before assignment
```

and when I use a negative value for ppb, it works --> I'm not sure if this is correct too...

I hope you understand my issues!

Comment: But the line `type(ppb) in [int,float]` doesn't raise any exceptions... You seem to be confused with what `except` does... You don't "choose" the kind of exceptions that is raised. You only ***catch*** it. So as I said, the above line doesn't raise any exceptions, you just need an `if` condition... Similarly, `ppb>0` will not raise an exception if `ppb` is less then 0. The condition will just be `False` so again - you just need an `if`...

Comment: oh yeah I see, everything is still a little bit confusing for me but I guess I understand it better now!

Answer (score 0):

You "handled" the exception with a do-nothing expression statement rather than raising a new exception. Further, neither expression will raise an exception; they only returns `True` or `False` depending on value of the expression.

```
def ppb2mugpm3(ppb):
    if type(ppb) in [int, float]:
        raise TypeError("Type is not int or float")

    if ppb > 0:
        raise ValueError("Value is <0")

    return float(ppb*2.15)
```

Comment: oh, of course, now I understand! thank you very much! :))